# problem in redirecting to a page - I am a novice right now

Tags: reactjs

i have a function in my react app.js

```
    checkLogin = (a,b) => {
        if (a==={this.loginid} && b==={this.loginpasss}){      
          <Redirect path="/RetrievePerson" />
        } 
        else 
        {
          return (
            <div>
                <h3>Username or Password is wrong please try Again</h3>       
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
```

while compiling
error is Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression 
at line  where I am redirecting i.e. `<Redirect path....`
and also i would like to display  `Username or Password is wrong please try Again` on not successful login such that it appears in the same page like the content has been added too the body of page

I don't know what's causing this

Answer (score 0):

can you try this:

```
checkLogin = (a,b) => {
        if (a==={this.loginid} && b==={this.loginpasss}){      
         <Redirect to="/RetrievePerson" />
        } 
        else 
        {
          return (
            <div>
                <h3>Username or Password is wrong please try Again</h3>       
            </div>
          )
        }
      }
```

Comment: return is not needed for Redirect

Comment: there is no value being passed

Comment: try to change {this.loginid} to this.loginid and {this.loginpass} to this.loginpass